# Is it possible to execute two roslaunch commands from a single python script?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run two different packages together for accumulating data from two different systems/sensors - Eg: roslaunch a_b ab.launch, roslaunch x_y xy.launch. I am currently calling two python programs to record the data but I want to be able to launch it simultaneously from the same python script so that I can manipulate the data from the two sensors inside one script. Is there a clean way of doing this?
Thanks in advance!

Sneha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272870/is-it-possible-to-execute-two-roslaunch-commands-from-a-single-python-script?/) by [i_robot_flight](https://answers.ros.org/users/32131/i_robot_flight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on 2017-10-13**:
maybe I don't understand your needs, but why not create a launch file that [includes](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include) both files?

**Comment by [i_robot_flight](https://answers.ros.org/users/32131/i_robot_flight/) on 2017-10-16**:
I actually have the python script running other functions before I need to open the ros packages of the sensors. Would it be more efficient for me to call the launch file in the python program rather than the roslaunch commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since bashrc is not setup before a desktop file is auto-launched at boot, the python api using "import roslaunch" fails with error "no module named roslaunch". Right now, since I have other function being performed through the python script before the ros drivers are needed, my workaround is to use os.system to directly run bash to source the files and launch the packages. If there is a better way of doing it, please do share!

---

Originally posted by [i_robot_flight](https://answers.ros.org/users/32131/i_robot_flight/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0